# Javascript - alert a object holding an XMLDocument or Document

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, dom

When I will alert an XMLDocument, it will definitely display [object] or [object - XMLDocument]. Suppose we have recieved the xml data from an XMLHttpRequest's response.

How will we convert this XML Document to string type variable so that we can display with an alert dialogue ? Please send pure JS code, I cannot use framework viz. JQuery etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try following,

in IE,

```
xmlObject.xml
```

other browsers,

```
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlObject)
```